# how to get count in whereHas closure in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want the list of users that in their tickets there is no `user_id` with `auth()->user()->id` :

```
$users = User::whereHas('tickets' , function($query) {
        $query->where('user_id' , '!=' , auth()->user()->id);
    })->get();
```

users model (relation ship) :

```
public function tickets(){
    return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class , 'to_id');
}
```

ticket table:

```
user_id // sender user
to_id // receiver user
```

I want to some thing like this :

```
    $users = User::whereHas('tickets' , function($query) {
        return $query->where('user_id' , '!=' , auth()->user()->id)-count() == 0;
    })->get();
```

I mean a list of users that there is no ticket between them and `auth()->user()` exists.
how to get that?

Comment: So you want a list of users which doesn't have any tickets excluding current logged in user?

Comment: yes you are right, how to get that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$users = User::whereNotExists(function ($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw(1))->from('tickets')->whereRaw('tickets.to_id = users.id')->where('tickets.user_id' , auth()->user()->id);
    })->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$users = User::where('id' , '!=' , auth()->user()->id)->doesntHave('tickets')->count();
```

USER Model

```
  public function tickets()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(TicketModel::class);
    }
```